# Sort Order of Image gallery is not working for Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting, slider

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 and there is feature for product using which one can sort images for gallery, but for me it is not working, actually the changes of sorting order are not saved.

Any other changes like add new image or excluding it is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the sort order only influenced the order of display in the item configuration page, not in the store.
In the store, they were displayed in the order in which they were uploaded.
To change the order, I removed the images and then added them back, one at a time, in the order I wanted them to display and this resolved the issue in the store.

Comment: Actully there was another module which has overwrite the sort order of gallery images.